# How to know If div BackGround Image is loaded

Tags: javascript, css, image, background, loading

I have an Apllication Which has many divs each having different image as background image as CSS... How can I know if the background image applied to the div is completely loaded...

Comment: as for me it is impossible, but I would like to know answer as well :)

Answer (score 1):

The [window.onload](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_body_onload.asp) event is fired when the page is complete loaded, which also includes the images

Comment: +1 was going to suggest this. Can also use JQuery .ready() as well if you prefer handling it with JQuery

Comment: @Alex, no `jquery.ready` is the same as DomLoaded event, this is BEFORE the images are downloaded. Most of the time you use the DomLoaded/ready event, but not in this case.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/ready/ "While JavaScript provides the load event for executing code when a page is rendered, this event does not get triggered until all assets such as images have been completely received."

Comment: @Alex: so it says: (on)load is called **after** images donwloading. Most of the time this is unwanted (too late), so they created the ready/domloaded. 
Same page: 
"In cases where code relies on loaded assets (for example, if the dimensions of an image are required), the code should be placed in a handler for the **load** event instead."

Comment: Window.onload may not work in my case as My divs are created dynamically but not onload...

Answer (score 0):

You need to 'preload' your background images first, then set them to divs

You can look at this question:

[Preloading images with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery)

Comment: also, this is another good read: http://engineeredweb.com/blog/09/12/preloading-images-jquery-and-javascript